# Input styling, why wont my block be displayed when invalid

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my input box as i want to be able to make part of the placeholder text bold.

I tried using the :valid/:invalid however for some odd reason the block is just not displayed in any cases.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code

```css
/* Search section */

.search_container {
  padding: 39px 27px;
}
.search_transparant_border {
  height: 90px;
}
.big_search_area {
  background: rgba(129, 163, 195, 0.7);
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 85%;
}
.big_search {
  background: url(../images/green_search_icon.png);
  width: 27px;
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.big_input_search {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
  color: #949494;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 10px 35px 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.big_search_area form p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 15px;
}
.big_search_area form p strong {
  color: #576877;
}
.big_search_area p {
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 60px;
  top: 17px;
}
.big_search_area form input:invalid + p {
  display: block;
}
.big_search_area form input:invalid {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.big_search_area form input:valid + p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Search section -->
<div class="search_container">
  <div class="search_transparant_border">
    <div class="big_search_area">
      <div style="position:relative;">
        <form action="/search/" method="get" style="position: relative">
          <input type="search" value="" class="big_input_search" name="query" required />
          <input class=big_search type=submit value="" />
          <p>{% trans "Search products e.g." %} <strong>ipod</strong>
          </p>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following part of your css, you are using `form input`. Since there are two inputs in the form => `input + p` will be available for `submit` input but you don't want that.

```
.big_search_area form input:invalid + p {
  display: block;
}
.big_search_area form input:invalid {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.big_search_area form input:valid + p {
  display: none;
}
```

So a solution using html/css only will be to move `<p> </p>` above the `submit` input as follows:

```
<input type="search" value="" class="big_input_search" name="query" required />
<p>{% trans "Search products e.g." %} <strong>ipod</strong>
<input class=big_search type=submit value="" />
```

Comment: Ahhh simple! thank you, spent an hour looking at this :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to try to select your `p` tag but, as the `p` isn't an adjacent sibling of the `input` you're validating (it's adjacent to your `submit` `input`, it will never be selected.

In order to select the `p`, you should instead use a [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

Furthermore, in order to simplify your CSS and avoid any potential issues down the road, you should use the class name you've given your `text` `input` in your selector.

And, finally, you don't need the `:invalid` selector as `p` is a block level element, so setting its `display` property to `block` is redundant.

To sum up, replace these two CSS rules:

```
.big_search_area form input:invalid + p {
    display: block;
}
.big_search_area form input:valid + p {
    display: none;
}
```

With this one:

```
.big_input_search:invalid~p{
    display:none;
}
```